# Grep --byte-offset not returning the offset (Grep version 2.5.1)

Tags: bash, grep, offset

Grep `--byte-offset` not returning the offset (Grep version 2.5.1)
Hi,
I am trying to get the position of a repeated string in a line using

Code:

```
grep -b -o "pattern"
```

In my server I am using GNU grep version 2.14 and the code is working fine. However when I am deploying the same code in a different server which is using GNU grep version 2.5.1 the code is not working properly. Even though the byte offset option is available there. Any idea how to solve it.

Example:

Code:

```
export string="abc cat mat rat cat bat cat fat rat tat tat cat"
echo $string|grep -b -o "cat"
```

Expected output (and supported in grep 2.14):

```
4:cat
16:cat
24:cat
44:cat
```

But same code with grep version 2.5.1 is giving the following output:

```
0:cat
cat
cat
cat
```

Please suggest..

Comment: Did you actually try it with the more verbose option, `--byte-offset`?

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to 2.14 if that fixes it for you? I'm not quite sure what you're expecting as an answer here.

Comment: Curiously, I have a RHEL 5.7 system with grep 2.5.1 which shows this problem. But, a latest 2.15 tar-ball built with default configure also reproduces that same problem. Then, if I move to a recent Ubuntu system (where installed 2.6.3 grep works fine) and compile the 2.15 sources there, it works fine. That seems to eliminate possible configure specifics. I wonder if there are other platform dependent effects I am seeing here.

Answer (score 5):

It was a bug in grep as some notes in its Changelog refer to it:

> ```
>     * src/grep.c (nlscan): Make this function more robust by removing
>       the undocumented assumption that its "lim" argument points
>       right after a line boundary.  This will be used later to fix
>       --byte-offset's broken behavior.  Patch #3769.
> ```

Use later versions (at least 2.5.3) where it seems fixed already.

Comment: I hit this on a RHEL 5.7 with grep 2.5.1 and tried the latest 2.15 tar-ball. Got a reproduction with that too (see my comment in the question for more details).

Comment: +1 Thank you for this answer -- saved me a lot of time banging my head against the wall. This is a particular problem for OS X, which has BSD grep 2.5.1 and has had it since at least version 10.8. I was able to work around it with the help of this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122945/99697