# Want to display position of match in string using grep command

Tags: regex, bash

Please help me with this

example string :

```
error on port 1:2:4
```

help me with grep command which would display the postion of 1:2:4 in that string considering space as delimeter .

expected result :

```
4:error on port 1:2:4
```

I have tried grep -b "1:2:4" filename ... but it returns

```
0:error on port 1:2:4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `awk` should work:

```
line='error on port 1:2:4'
awk -v line="$line" -v s='1:2:4' '$1==s{print NR, line}' RS=' ' OFS=':' <<< "$line"
4:error on port 1:2:4
```

Comment: No worries and thanks @Tiago I have removed my downvote from your answer. But I think your answer is now very similar to AvinashRaj's answer.

Comment: true, but I am matching a pattern, he's doing an exact comparisson anyways I only edited because the answer was accepted and it was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could use awk for printing the column number which stores the corresponding value,

```
$ echo 'error on port 1:2:4' | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i=="1:2:4") print i}}'
4
```

To get your desired result,

```
$ echo 'error on port 1:2:4' | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i=="1:2:4") print i":",$0}}'
4: error on port 1:2:4
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

I totally misunderstood the question and it got accepted, my apologies.

The correct answer is below:

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i ~/1:2:4/){print i": "$0} } }' <<< "error on port 1:2:4"
4: error on port 1:2:4
```

As suggested  in the comments:

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i ~/1:2:4/){print i": "$0} } }' <<< "there's an error on port 1:2:4"
6: there's an error on port 1:2:4
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of grep. Older versions had a bug (see below)

If you are on the correct version try it with -o option. This worked for me on v2.6.3.

```
$ grep -b -o '1:2:4' file 
14:1:2:4
```

Reference
[Grep --byte-offset not returning the offset (Grep version 2.5.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802707/grep-byte-offset-not-returning-the-offset-grep-version-2-5-1)